# How can i use Key Vault for connection strings in Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have followed the following for How to reference Key Vault connection strings from an Azure App Service.

```
https://davecallan.com/how-to-reference-key-vault-connection-strings-from-an-azure-app- 
service/
```

The connection string has a name of "sqlconnection" in the App Service Configuration. I then deleted this entry from the Configuration Json file and restarted the Web app.

I then try to connect but it gives a database error with no details.

Any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment like below:***

I created a key vault with **Azure role-based access control (RBAC)** like below:

[image]

Make sure to add **Key Vault Administrator role** in Access control like below:

[image]

Generate a key vault secret under setting. While generating secret of type as Manual name and set the value to the current SQL Database connection string stored in the Application **`web.config`**

[image]

Try to use Secret value connection string of your sql database like below:

[image]

Then you can able to see Secret Identifier like below:

[image]

In your web app -> under setting click configuration -> click new connection string

[image]

Type the name of the connection string and set the value `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=VALUE), where the VALUE`

[image]

In Identity under setting -> make sure to add system assigned status as on like below:

[image]

Click on the "Role Assignments" button and then Add keyvault secrets  user role like below:

[image]

As you are facing database error with no details you can check the  Log4net errors under Portals_default\Logs.

***Reference***:

[Connection strings and app settings not working properly on Azure App Service · Issue #4227 · dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform · GitHub](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/issues/4227)

Comment: I have tried all of this and no luck , still doesnt work

Comment: Kindly check this reference:- [Ref1](https://intelequia.com/blog/post/2070/storing-azure-app-service-secrets-on-azure-key-vault) & [Ref2](https://davecallan.com/how-to-reference-key-vault-connection-strings-from-an-azure-app-service/)